# Upgrade xmlRpc version form 1.1 to 4.8

Tags: php, xml-rpc

yesterday upgraded php from 5.5 to 8.1, it gave me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: xml_parse(): Argument #1 ($parser) must be of type XMLParser, null given in /var/www/html/app/library/xmlrpc/xmlRpcClient.php:90 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 /var/www/html/app/library/xmlrpc/xmlRpcClient.php(90): xml_parse() 
> #1 /var/www/html/app/library/xmlrpc/xmlRpcClient.php(151): XML->parse() 
> #2 /var/www/html/app/library/xmlrpc/xmlRpcClient.php(397): XML_unserialize() 
> #3 /var/www/html/app/controller.php(271): XMLRPC_request() 
> #4 /var/www/html/app/style/aura/index.php(450): include('...') 
> #5 /var/www/html/app/index.html.php(25): include_once('...') 
> #6 /var/www/html/app/index.php(177): require_once('...') 
> #7 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/app/library/xmlrpc/xmlRpcClient.php on line 90

I've fixed some code, but i'm afraid need to update library. How can do it from command line or anyhow quickly?

Comment: Thats a HUGE JUMP. Did you check through all the version upgrade notes for each version between 5.5 and 8.1

Comment: example function fix -> &$parser to $parser, in all code.

Comment: Error at line 90: xml_parse($this->parser, $data); 
        return $this->document;

Comment: I don't want to sound like a troll, but Aura xml-rpc seems to be a dead project, or at least deeply dormant. You might be better off moving to a library which is well supported and tested with php 8.1 and 8.2, such as php-xmlrpc...